# E_NOINTERFACE error while creating com local server

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, com

I have created a COM local server(exe) sample project using ATL wizard in VS2008.
but when I use cocreateinstance to create the COM object, I am getting an error "E_NOINTERFACE".

As I know that "regsvr32" can be used to register com components and their respective interfaces but those are for in process com dlls, so do we need some extra steps apart from just launching com server exe before we make a call to cocreateintsance.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Regards
Ashish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a local server your client will run in a different process. If you have a server with a custom interface instead of IDispathch you need to marshal the interface. The interface marshaling is done in the proxy/stub. This is implemented in a DLL what will be loaded in the client process as well as in the server process.

Create and/or register the proxy/stub DLL.

Comment: Either this or using typelib marshalling where applicable.

Comment: @sharptooth Do we address the same with "typelib marshalling" and "IDispatch"?

Comment: Thanks a lot harper, registering the proxy stub dll solved my problem.

Comment: @harper: Yes, typelib marshaller will be happy to marshall interfaces inherited from `IDispatch` if they are Automation-compatible.